# Liquid metal between die and IHS: Problems with vertical mount?

Tags: cpu, thermal-paste, cpu-temperature

While ambient air temperature and humidity stayed the same, temperatures on my Intel Core i7 6700k @stock are slightly increasing. It is cooled by a beQuiet Dark Rock Pro 3, thermal compound is Arctic MX4-Silver. So, in Desktop Idle, I achieve 22-23 °C and in some heavy load (Cinebench R15 CPU --> 923 points (880 are the normal value for a stock i7 6700k, but AFAIK without XMP to DDR4-3200Mhz) gives you 53-54 °C, X-Plane 11 while loading (single thread graphics!) 60 °C) temperatures are higher than after initial build (~45°C).

Big question: is delidding worth the pain and moreover: can I apply liquid metal cooling solutions between die and IHS, if I mount the CPU vertically (like in the typical configuration, because almost no one has test bench setups for his pc)? Could it just flow out and cause shortages?

Comment: If you're worried about the temperature difference from when it was built, it would be worth re-applying the TIM and see if that improves matters before going to de-lidding. There's a range of temperatures at which the CPU will be fine, and yours hasn't exceeded that.

Comment: “Could it just flow out and cause shortages?” - Liquid metal can indeed.  So take the required preventative steps to avoid that.  Coating the few exposed traces can help with that.  Using the correct amount is the real solution

Answer (score 1):

I would not bother as long as the temperature stays below TCase at maximum CPU stress. There is too much to go wrong to fiddle around for a few °C.